# Matlab urlread button click on homepage

Tags: matlab, button, urlread

I try to read data from the homepage 
*https://www.apg.at/emwebapgrem/AuctionResults.do* 
with Matlab.

I already managed to filter the relevant type and date with the command

```
[str, ~] = urlread(['https://www.apg.at/emwebapgrem/AuctionResults.do?', ...
                        'auctionType=SECONDARY_CONTROL_POWER', ...
                        '&periodBegin.date=01.01.2014', ...
                        '&periodEnd.date=10.01.2014', ...
                        '&auctionOpenedFrom.date=', ...
                        '&auctionOpenedTo.date=', ...
                        '&doFilter=Filtern']);
```

Now I want Matlab to hit the *Detail* button on the homepage right next to the first auction and output the data of the first auction as a string. Any ideas how to make Matlab address the page that appears, when you hit the *Detail* button?

Thank you!!

Comment: DDOS using matlab? ^_^

Comment: I need to clarify the problem. I was able to build the first part of the URL with the parameters as stated above. On the result page there is a link invoking JavaScript. `onclick=auctionResultListForm.auctionResultListAction.value='detail';auctionResultListForm.auctionResultListIndex.value=0;submitForm(auctionResultListForm);` It does not change the URL but brings the actual results I need. Is there a way to invoke the JavaScript from Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. This is the solution link I have to call where the number behind 'auctionReultListIndex' describes which bid in the list I want to see:

https://www.apg.at/emwebapgrem/AuctionResults.do?auctionType=SECONDARY_CONTROL_ENERGY&periodBegin.date=02.03.2015&periodEnd.date=03.03.2015&auctionOpenedFrom.date=&auctionOpenedTo.date=&doFilter=Filtern&auctionResultListIndex=0&auctionResultListAction=detail

So the Maltab code is:

```
[str, ~] = urlread(['https://www.apg.at/emwebapgrem/AuctionResults.do?auctionType=SECONDARY_CONTROL_ENERGY&periodBegin.date=02.03.2015&periodEnd.date=03.03.2015&auctionOpenedFrom.date=&auctionOpenedTo.date=&doFilter=Filtern&auctionResultListIndex=0&auctionResultListAction=detail']);
```

Then the parameter str contains a string with the specific bid details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Matlab is not able to do this by itself. In your context Matlab is just a client which gets the content of an URL with `urlread`. There is no such thing as a `urlclickhere` or `urldothisaction` function ...

Your only option with Matlab is to build up the URL associated with the button from the information available on the main page, and then call `urlread` again.

If you are not bound with Matlab, [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is an interesting Jython project that might be helpful here.